# Erro: "informações insuficientes sobre a tabela base para atualização" Delphi Berlin + banco de dados SAP MAXDB no Windows 10 64bits 10

Tags: delphi

Sou iniciante aqui no site, tentei por um print mas não sei se da. mas vou tentar detalhar todo o cenário:

1. Windows 10 64bits (maquina onde tenho o delphi berlin instalado e com o sistema teste em execução)
2. conexão com banco via *ODBC*
3. Server 2003 com o BD SAP MAXDB instalado
4. Aplicação simples *VCL Delphi Berlin* com `TADOConnection` + `TADOQuery` + `DATASource` + `DBGrid` + `DBNavigator` e uma query exemplo: `select * from CAIXA`
5. A query funciona normalmente ao dar open traz alguns registro inseridos de outro sistema.
6. testo no `dbgrid` dando um `append` na linha e em seguida digito em 2 campos (`cod` e `descr`) e quando vai dar o `aplyUpdates` (botão de aplicar no Navigator) que retorna esse erro: "informações insuficientes sobre a tabela base para atualização"

Se eu usar clientDataSet ao invés de TADOquery para aplicar o post/applyupdades  o problema não acontece porém não grava os dados no banco

Se eu rodar esse app em versões anteriores ao Windows 10 esse problema não ocorre e grava normalmente. Já testei em 8.1, 7 e Vista.
No Windows server 2012 esse problema também ocorre.

Segue o código abaixo das 2 únicas Unit que tenho no projeto:

```
unit Unit1;

interface

uses
  Winapi.Windows, Winapi.Messages, System.SysUtils, System.Variants, System.Classes, Vcl.Graphics,
  Vcl.Controls, Vcl.Forms, Vcl.Dialogs, Data.DB, Data.Win.ADODB, Vcl.StdCtrls,
  FireDAC.Stan.Intf, FireDAC.Stan.Option, FireDAC.Stan.Error, FireDAC.UI.Intf,
  FireDAC.Phys.Intf, FireDAC.Stan.Def, FireDAC.Stan.Pool, FireDAC.Stan.Async,
  FireDAC.Phys, FireDAC.Phys.ODBC, FireDAC.Phys.ODBCDef, FireDAC.VCLUI.Wait,
  FireDAC.Stan.Param, FireDAC.DatS, FireDAC.DApt.Intf, FireDAC.DApt,
  FireDAC.Phys.ODBCBase, FireDAC.Comp.DataSet, FireDAC.Comp.Client;

type
  TForm1 = class(TForm)
    Button1: TButton;
    ADOConnection1: TADOConnection;
    fivenews: TADOConnection;
    procedure Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
  private
    { Private declarations }
  public
    { Public declarations }
  end;

var
  Form1: TForm1;

implementation

{$R *.dfm}

uses Unit2;

procedure TForm1.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
begin
  Application.CreateForm(TForm2, Form2);
  Form2.Show;
end;

end.
```

---

```
unit Unit2;

interface

uses
  Winapi.Windows, Winapi.Messages, System.SysUtils, System.Variants, System.Classes, Vcl.Graphics,
  Vcl.Controls, Vcl.Forms, Vcl.Dialogs, Data.DB, Vcl.Grids, Vcl.DBGrids,
  Data.Win.ADODB, Vcl.StdCtrls, Vcl.Mask, Vcl.DBCtrls, Vcl.ExtCtrls;

type
  TForm2 = class(TForm)
    qCaixa: TADOQuery;
    DBGrid1: TDBGrid;
    dsCaixa: TDataSource;
    qCaixaCX_CODIGO: TBCDField;
    qCaixaCX_NOME: TStringField;
    Label1: TLabel;
    DBEdit1: TDBEdit;
    Label2: TLabel;
    DBEdit2: TDBEdit;
    DBNavigator1: TDBNavigator;
    qCaixaCX_SALDO: TFloatField;
    procedure FormShow(Sender: TObject);
  private
    { Private declarations }
  public
    { Public declarations }
  end;

var
  Form2: TForm2;

implementation

{$R *.dfm}

uses Unit1;

procedure TForm2.FormShow(Sender: TObject);
begin
  qCaixa.Open;
end;

end.
```

Comment: está detalhado, não entendi o que mais você precisa mas vamos la:

Comment: Coloque um [mcve] que reproduza esse cenário que você descreveu.

Comment: não entendi o que preciso por aqui pra deixar claro pra você. exemplo simples desse e você fecha a pergunta

Comment: Talvez quando você diz "que retorna esse erro" devesse informar o erro?

Comment: blz, é que quando editei o texto havia perdido a mensagem mas o erro é esse: informações insuficientes sobre a tabela base para atualização